# Why do I have type 'never' on my decimal?

Tags: reactjs, types, typeerror

I'm trying to write code that rounds a number to the nearest hundredth, but if it only goes to the tenths place, it adds on a zero.

For some reason, my code says that my decimal has type 'never'. Any solutions?

`newCost` is my decimal. The cost variable is my displayer.

```
let newCost =
   Math.round(
     (parseFloat(cost.textContent) + parseFloat(this.state.price)) *
     1.1 *
     100
   ) / 100;
if (typeof newCost === "float" && typeof newCost * 10 === "int") {
  cost.textContent = newCost.toString().concat("0");
} else {
  cost.textContent = newCost;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve by reading your first paragraph. Could you add some sample inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***toFixed***:

```
let newCost = ((cost.textContent + this.state.price) * 1.1).toFixed(2);
```

If the decimal is of 2 digits, it just takes them. If not, then it automatically appends `0` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The `typeof` operator can never output `"float"` or `"int"`; all numbers result in `"number"`. As a result, it's impossible to enter the `if` statement. Since it's impossible, typescript indicates this by narrowing the type on `newCost` to `never`.

One possible way to change your code is to use `Number.isInteger`:

```
if (!Number.isInteger(newCost) && Number.isInteger(newCost * 10))
```